Error when using "import MetaTrader5" in Python
I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling numpy. Uninstalled reinstalled MetaTrader5 as well.
Tried the following code
pip install -U numpy

Installed an older version "numpy<2.0". Nothing seems to be working.
This error pops up only when I try to import MetaTrader5


The error message indicates that the MetaTrader5 module (or another module it depends on) was compiled using an older version of numpy (1. x) and is not compatible with the newer version of NumPy(2.1.0) that you currently have installed. Here are some steps you can take to solve this issue.
Option 1: Downgrade NumPy
If you don’t need features from NumPy 2.x, downgrading to a compatible version of NumPy (e.g., 1.24.x) should resolve the issue.
Uninstall the current version of NumPy:  pip uninstall numpy
Install an older, compatible version of NumPy:  pip install numpy<2.0

I have tried this already doesn't seem to work

Restarting kernel is needed according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/78641405/3809427

Worked for me when I downgraded to NumPy 1.26.4
enter image description here

Please avoid including code/data/errors as images. Copy-pasting as text allows such string to be searched, and copy-pasted in turn by who is trying to reproduce your issue. Have a look here for a discussion on the topic.

Use numpy version 1.26.4 and it will work. it worked for me.
start by uninstalling numpy:
pip uninstall numpy

Then install version 1.26.4
pip install numpy==1.26.4


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
